# Python pandas drops duplicates in wrong order

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

When running drop duplicates on python pandas there seems to be a bug which causes the DataFrame to be sorted in the wrong order.

Specifically, I was trying to provide two columns to perform the drop duplicates on. Instead of:

```
df.drop_duplicates(['a', 'b'], inplace = True)
```

I had:

```
df.drop_duplicates('a', 'b', inplace = True)
```

Which I think caused the problem as it disappeared with the addition of square brackets.

I don't understand why this: a) doesn't bug out for incorrectly defined inputs, b) changes the order of what is dropped and kept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [docs for `drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) say the arguments are:

> - subset : column label or sequence of labels, optional
>     Only consider certain columns for identifying duplicates, by default use all of the columns
> - take_last : boolean, default False
>     Take the last observed row in a row. Defaults to the first row
> - inplace : boolean, default False
>     Whether to drop duplicates in place or to return a copy
> - cols : kwargs only argument of subset [deprecated]

So, in your wring call, it probably used `b` for the `take_last`, which it evaluated as a Boolean `True`. This is standard practice in Python (checking for wrong inputs is not comprehensive).

Comment: Hi Ami, so the default boolean interpretation of a string is True, and that got passed through to the optional value. Makes sense.
Thanks

Comment: @Tom the boolean interpretation of a string is *whether it is nonempty*.